# R dyn.load "Symbol not found" error, even though C++ code builds fine

Tags: c++, r, gurobi

I have a simple C++ program that I can build successfully using `clang++` on my Mac (Mavericks) but that fails when built with `R CMD SHLIB` and loaded with `dyn.load` in R.

This is the C++ code (stored in `simple.cpp`), which uses the Gurobi optimizer:

```
#include "gurobi_c++.h"
#include <iostream>

void fxn() {
  GRBEnv env = GRBEnv();  // Create a Gurobi environment
  GRBModel colgen = GRBModel(env);  // Create empty model object
  colgen.addVar(0, 1, 0.0, GRB_BINARY);  // Add binary variable to model
  std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  fxn();
  return 0;
}
```

I can successfully compile and run this code using `clang++`, linking to the Gurobi libraries:

```
$ clang++ simple.cpp -I/Library/gurobi562/mac64/include \
  -L/Library/gurobi562/mac64/lib -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi56 -stdlib=libstdc++ \
  -lpthread -lm
$ ./a.out
Hello world
```

I am able to compile successfully with `R CMD SHLIB`:

```
$ MAKEFLAGS="PKG_CXXFLAGS=-I/Library/gurobi562/mac64/include" R CMD SHLIB \
  simple.cpp -L/Library/gurobi562/mac64/lib -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi56 \
  -stdlib=libstdc++ -lpthread -lm
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG \
  -I/usr/local/include   -I/Library/gurobi562/mac64/include -fPIC  -mtune=core2 \
  -g -O2  -c simple.cpp -o simple.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup \
  -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib \
  -o simple.so simple.o -L/Library/gurobi562/mac64/lib -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi56 \
  -stdlib=libstdc++ -lpthread -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. \
  -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

However, `dyn.load("simple.so")` fails in R:

```
Error in dyn.load("simple.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '[path]/simple.so':
  dlopen([path]/simple.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN8GRBModel6addVarEdddcNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE
  Referenced from: [path]/simple.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in [path]/simple.so
```

From `c++filt`, I can see that the missing symbol is `GRBModel::addVar(double, double, double, char, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)`, which should be provided by one of the Gurobi libraries I'm linking.

From previous posts, I've gathered that these "Symbol not found" errors often occur from simply not linking the correct libraries, but I've been able to successfully compile and run `simple.cpp` and I'm passing the same linking options to `R CMD SHLIB`.

The following are the contents of my `~/.R/Makevars` file:

```
CC=clang
CXX=clang++
```

**Edit** I think the issue might have to do with the option `-stdlib=libstdc++` that I'm using when I compile the code. When I remove this option from the first build (the working invocation of `clang++`), the first linker error I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "GRBModel::addVar(double, double, double, char, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _fxn in simple-pRHAEs.o
```

This is the same undefined symbol that's causing `dyn.load` to fail.

Comment: I suspect that R is not able to find the library when loading `simple.so`. Is the location of the gurobi libraries included in `ld_library_path` (or whatever it is called on macs)?

Comment: Also it is strange to have a main in a library, this might cause problems and you may want to put your `fxn` in an `extern "C" {}` to be able to call it from R

Comment: `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` yields the correct location `:/Library/gurobi562/mac64/lib`, and I also have it stored in `R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- not sure if that matters. Commenting out the main function and adding `extern "C"` didn't help with the `dyn.load` issue, though I'll be sure to do both so I can eventually call my function.

Comment: `-stdlib=libstdc++` is required for Gurobi Optimizer 5.6

Comment: @GregGlockner thanks! The standard library ended up being the core of the issue -- I was already passing `-stdlib=libstdc++` to the linker but I also needed to add `-stdlib=libstdc++` to `PKG_CXXFLAGS` so it would be used in the compile phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue, which turned out to be related to how I was providing the argument `-stdlib=libstdc++` to `R CMD SHLIB`. `R CMD SHLIB` invokes `clang++` twice, first as a compilation phase to build an object file (`simple.o` in my case) and then to link that file into a shared object (`simple.so` in my case). `R CMD SHLIB` was only passing the `-stdlib=libstdc++` argument to the second invocation, but we need it to also provide the argument to the first invocation of `clang++`. We can do this by adding `-stdlib=libstdc++` to `PKG_CXXFLAGS`:

```
$ PKG_CXXFLAGS="-I/Library/gurobi562/mac64/include -stdlib=libstdc++" R CMD SHLIB \
  simple.cpp -L/Library/gurobi562/mac64/lib -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi56 \
  -stdlib=libstdc++ -lpthread -lm
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  \
  -I/usr/local/include   -I/Library/gurobi562/mac64/include -stdlib=libstdc++ \
  -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c simple.cpp -o simple.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup \
  -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib \
  -o simple.so simple.o -L/Library/gurobi562/mac64/lib -lgurobi_c++ -lgurobi56 \
  -stdlib=libstdc++ -lpthread -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. \
  -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

Now, `dyn.load("simple.so")` works without error from R (though as mentioned by @MartinMorgan and @JanvanderLaan, I'll need to expose my functions using `extern "C"` or an alternative to actually be able to call them from R).

Answer (score 0):

R is expecting C linkage, but you've provided C++ linkage. One solution is

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void fxn() {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

with

```
$ R --vanilla CMD SHLIB tmp.cpp && R --vanilla -e "dyn.load('tmp.so'); .C('fxn')"
clang++ -I/home/mtmorgan/bin/R-devel/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -ggdb -O0 -c tmp.cpp -o tmp.o
clang++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib -o tmp.so tmp.o -L/home/mtmorgan/bin/R-devel/lib -lR
> dyn.load('tmp.so'); .C('fxn')
Hello world
list()
```

Comment: That shouldn't cause an error when loading the library as reported by the OP. It would only make it almost impossible to call `fxn` as its name gets mangled.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately adding `extern "C"` doesn't fix the `dyn.load` issue.