# R dyn.load gives "undefined symbol" error

Tags: r, c, shared-libraries

I am writing a shared library that itself uses the [uthash](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/) library in C under Ubuntu. I am going to use this shared library in R. For this purpose I have created a package.c file where the main code is stored. In order to use CALLOC function (a part of the uthash) I have included uthash.h in the beginning of package.c. In the body of package.c the CALLOC function is called.

I can build package.c without any problem by running:

```
R CMD SHLIB package.c
```

This is the output of the above command in the console:

```
gcc -I"/usr/local/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c package.c -o package.o
gcc -shared -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o package.so package.o -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -lR
```

It produces two files "package.o" and "package.so". I load package.so in R using dyn:

```
dyn.load("package.so")
```

But it gives the following error message:

```
Error in dyn.load("package.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/me/package/package.so':
  /home/me/package/package.so: undefined symbol: memoryMap
```

I searched for a solution and found [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2005-September/034616.html). According to what is written there, here is the the output of "ldd package.so" and "nm -g package.so" commands:

"ldd package.so" output:

```
$ ldd package.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd283da000)
libR.so => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd3643b4000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd3649a8000)
```

"nm -g package.so" outout:

```
$ nm -g package.so
0000000000202088 B __bss_start
                 U calloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000202088 D _edata
0000000000202090 B _end
00000000000016d8 T _fini
                 U free@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000001260 T getSteadyStateDistribution_R
             w __gmon_start__
00000000000008b0 T _init
                 U INTEGER
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U malloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14
                 U memoryMap
                 U __printf_chk@@GLIBC_2.3.4
                 U REAL
                 U Rf_error
                 U Rf_isNull
                 U Rf_length
0000000000000d70 T simulate
0000000000000e50 T simulate_R
                 U __stack_chk_fail@@GLIBC_2.4
0000000000000aa0 T stateTransition
                 U unif_rand
```

I have also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816022/r-dyn-load-symbol-not-found-error-even-though-c-code-builds-fine) but still could not find a solution for my problem.

**Edit:**

Here is an example to reproduce the error:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include "uthash.h"

typedef struct
{
  // a pointer to the allocated memory
  void * ptr;
  // used by the hash table
  UT_hash_handle hh;
} AllocatedMemory;

// map that stores all allocated memory pointers
// to free them on interrupt
extern AllocatedMemory * memoryMap;


static inline void* CALLOC(size_t n, size_t sz)
{
  void * ptr = calloc(n, sz);

  if (ptr == NULL)
    error("Out of memory!");

  AllocatedMemory * m = calloc(1, sizeof(AllocatedMemory));
  m->ptr = ptr;
  HASH_ADD_PTR(memoryMap, ptr, m);
  return ptr;
}

SEXP example_R(SEXP vec_R) {
    unsigned int n = length(vec_R);
    unsigned int * v = CALLOC(n, sizeof(unsigned int));
}
```

If the above code is stored in "example.c", compile it using:

```
R CMD SHLIB example.c
```

It will produce the files example.o and example.so. Then load the so file in R:

```
dyn.load('example.so')
```

Comment: There is a lot that can be said here.  So three years ago I sat down and put it all into a little paper that is also an Rcpp vignette:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06416

Comment: For more hands-on help it would be beneficial if you could a [minimally complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) availble, maybe via `git` repo?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thank you for your comment. I have included an example to reproduce the error message.

Comment: Well first point is 'do not do that' -- see [Writing R Extension](https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-exts/) about the alloc you should use with R (accessing R's memory pool). The second point is what looks like a fairly standard error.  You declare `extern AllocatedMemory * memoryMap;` but never provide it.  And the linker tells you exactly that: an external reference to `memoryMap` is referenced, but no object is provided.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel your first point does not seem to be relevant because of the error message. About your second point, the C code is compiled without any error. But when I load the .so file the "undefined symbol" error is issued.

Comment: Compiler != linker. So the second point remains very much relevant because that is your error. And as you are learning with this project _just because you compile does not imply you link._ Your very error is exactly as I said: you reference an external resource you do not supply, and the linker tells you about it. (First point is a 'do not do that if you ever want to be on CRAN, so not a deadly errror but a recommendation.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel the program is both compiled and linked without a problem. The error message is issued when I want to use it in R.

Comment: ... which is when the _dynamic linker_ invoked by `dyn,load()` tried (and fails, of course) to use the _external reference_ you added _but did not supply_.  But I will stop trying to help you now as you apparently know better, despite it not working.  Best of luck; you can try the same with two small C files on the command line. It is the same logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the *minimal* change to make your example compile *and load* i.e. link dynamically:

```
$ diff -u question.orig.c question.c
--- question.orig.c     2022-12-22 09:41:46.483509755 -0600
+++ question.c  2022-12-22 09:44:45.217420621 -0600
@@ -12,7 +12,8 @@
 
 // map that stores all allocated memory pointers
 // to free them on interrupt
-extern AllocatedMemory * memoryMap;
+AllocatedMemory memoryMapInstance;
+AllocatedMemory *memoryMap = &memoryMapInstance;
 
 
 static inline void* CALLOC(size_t n, size_t sz)
$
```

Instead of the reference to an `extern` instance you fail to supply, but one instance (cheaply) on the stack and define the pointer you need as its address. In a real program you would allocate this on the heap.

Another remaining error is that your `example_R` is wrong as you claim to take and return a `SEXP`. But we leave this for another time.

Now with a simple wrapper `questions.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

R CMD SHLIB question.c
R -e 'dyn.load("question.so")'
```

we get another warning because the return from `CALLOC` is unused -- but no longer an error on load.

```
$ ./question.sh 
ccache gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-ignored-attributes -std=gnu99 -c question.c -o question.o
question.c: In function ‘example_R’:
question.c:34:20: warning: unused variable ‘v’ [-Wunused-variable]
   34 |     unsigned int * v = CALLOC(n, sizeof(unsigned int));
      |                    ^
question.c:35:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   35 | }
      | ^
ccache gcc -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o question.so question.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR

R version 4.2.2 Patched (2022-11-10 r83330) -- "Innocent and Trusting"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> dyn.load("question.so")
> 
> 
$
```

No error.

(You can ignore the compiler settings, and use of `ccache` I have locally. The warning is real.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I provided the example from the R package BoolNet (https://github.com/cran/BoolNet/) where in attractor_search_interface.c the CALLOC function is called in line 56 and common.h is included in line 5. In the line 68 of common.h, the declaration is exactly same as the example (extern AllocatedMemory * memoryMap;). Since this is a CRAN package how is it compiled and installed without such error?

Comment: Maybe it could help to read up a little on the meaning of `extern` in C. I presume the listed package _defines the symbol in another file_ as I suggested to you do too.  Now that you have another working example, you can cut it down to pieces slowly til it resembles your experiment,  Try it at each step and you will see very clearly what action breaks it.